# AWS : How to use CodeBuild to approve the approval rule template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

whenever a PR is created code build triggers runs some tests and gives the result.
based on the result I have a code commit approval rule template created which needs to be approved from codebuild.
In this case, codebuild is not considering the approval rule template created.

Instead, it's marking the PR as approved when successful -  when I run

```
aws codecommit update-pull-request-approval-state  --pull-request-id $pullRequestId --approval-state APPROVE --revision-id $revisionId
```

I need help on how do i tell my codebuild to approve the template rule which i have created?

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear. What exactly are you doing? What is your `buildspec.yml`? What's wrong with it? What errors do you get?

Comment: In my build spec file, I have a post-build command which will update the PR based on the result. if my build is passed I want to update the PR state to approve.
I have created an approval rule template and I want to approve that template but the code build is marking the PR approved but not the approval rule template

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think you can follow these steps:

- In the CodeBuild for PR-Created action, you put your test commands in build  section
- Base on the results of commands above, you can decide what to do next.
  This is the example one:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - test commands 1
      - test commands 2
  post_build:
    commands:
      - |-
          if [ "$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING" -gt "0" ]; then
            aws codecommit ...
          else
            notify some channels
          fi
```

Comment: yes I am doing the same thing but the problem I am facing is the the status of approval rule template is still showing "rule not satisfied" but under approvals of the PR I get a note saying its approved fom code build

Comment: Can you show me the approval rule? And the output from the command change approval state also. "Rule not satisfied" means the approve from CodeBuild is not enough

Comment: I have attached the screen shots above

Comment: Your approval rule does not have anything. Try to create one 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-create-pull-request-approval-rule.html

Comment: https://devato.com/post/codecommit-codebuild-pull-request-workflow
I am following this

Comment: I don't have access to your account to make sure that you are follow right. Try to check the official documentation that I pasted above for the right configuration. I think you are not configuring template correctly.